# Android OpenGL works on emulator but not phone

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, glulookat

I have the following code for the Renderer:

```
package hello.project;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.GLU;

public class HelloOpenGLES10Renderer implements Renderer {

private Square      square;
private Square2         square2;// the square
private Context     context;
private Context     context2;
public static int w,h;


/** Constructor to set the handed over context */
public HelloOpenGLES10Renderer(Context context) {
    this.square     = new Square();
    this.square2        = new Square2();
    this.context=context;


}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    /*Square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square.getSex()); 
    Square2.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square2.getHair()); 
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)w / (float)h, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 1, 5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f);
    square.draw(gl);
    square2.draw(gl);*/

    // clear Screen and Depth Buffer
    Square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square.getSex()); 
    Square2.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square2.getHair()); 
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f);   
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      // Reset the Modelview Matrix
      gl.glLoadIdentity();
     // GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      // Drawing
      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);  // move 5 units INTO the screen
      square.draw(gl);
      square2.draw(gl); 
}


public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {           //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1;             //Making Height Equal One
    }

    w=width;
    h=height;
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();        //Reset The Projection Matrix

    //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();        //Reset The Modelview Matrix
}


public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
      // Load the texture for the square
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);    //Enable Smooth Shading
    //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    //gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
      Square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square.getSex());
    //  gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER, 0.5f);

      gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  //Black Background
      gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);      //Depth Buffer Setup
      gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_NEVER);    //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

      //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
      gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

     }
}
```

If I use the current code from the `onDrawFrame` it works perfect for the emulator, but on the phone the `SurfaceView` is blank and i get nothing.
I found on a post that i should use GLU.gluLookAt(); instead of gl.glLoadIdentity();
If I do that(the code that is commented in the onDrawFrame) it works, i get the background, but my textures are not loaded, neither on the phone or the emulator. What do i have to do so i could load them and the app to work?

EDIT1: I commented the `GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)w / (float)h, 0.1f, 100.0f);` line from the `onDrawFrame` function and now it shows my textures, but the program force closes after a couple of seconds.

I get the next LogCat Errors:

```
 06-29 14:28:07.126: E/Adreno200-EGL(4825): eglLockWindowSurface: failed to map the memory for fd=54 offs=7385088
 06-29 14:28:07.126: E/Adreno200-EGL(4825): egliSwapWindowSurface: oglSwapBuffer failed
 06-29 14:28:07.126: E/EglHelper(4825): eglSwapBuffers glGetError = %d1285
 06-29 14:28:07.126: E/Adreno200-EGL(4825): eglLockWindowSurface: failed to map the memory for fd=54 offs=7385088
 06-29 14:28:07.276: W/dalvikvm(4825): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
 06-29 14:28:07.276: E/AndroidRuntime(4825): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
 06-29 14:28:07.276: E/AndroidRuntime(4825): java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 06-29 14:28:07.276: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1084)
 06-29 14:28:07.276: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1042)
 06-29 14:28:07.276: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1368)
 06-29 14:28:07.276: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1122)
 06-29 14:28:09.268: I/Process(4825): Sending signal. PID: 4825 SIG: 9
```

Any ideeas what that could mean?

Comment: perhaps your loadGLTexture() calls in onDrawFrame() try to (re-)load the texture for every frame and you thus your memory gets full?

Comment: yeah, i noticed too, and i had a boolean implemented in there, and now it's all good, i was on my way to answer my own question, but you sir, did it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had in my onDrawFrame() this 2 functions:

```
Square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square.getSex()); 
Square2.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square2.getHair());
```

And they kept reloading at every frame till the memory would be full and it would crash.
changed it with:

```
if (Project.ifDraw){
        Square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square.getSex()); 
        Square2.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context,Square2.getHair());
        Project.ifDraw=false;
    }
```

In my Project class:

```
public static boolean ifDraw=true;
```

OnClickListeners have implemented:

```
 mGLView.invalidate();
ifDraw=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC` is mostly an error due to not handling the `glSurfaceView` correctly.

You must notify `glSurfaceView` about the current activity lifecycle. See here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html

Also, how big is your texture, and how do you ensure it is in the right format?

Comment: the textures where the right format. the problem was loading the textures in onDraw causing it to use all the memory and crash